# idempotency task - installing a plugin kibana

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci

I'm struggling  to create an task that **will install a Kibana Plugin** with the statement "**changed_when:...**", the **playbook** is **running in --check mode** and I need to met "idempotency condition" but every time I get **"Idempotency failure for test $name"**

**Task name**

```
- name: Install kibana plugins
  command: "/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-plugin install {{ name_of_plugin }} --allow-root"
  register: InstallingPluginsResult
  changed_when: InstallingPluginsResult.stdout is search("Extraction complete")
  tags:
    - kibana-plugins
```

**Output task results would be:**

```
TASK [kibana : Install kibana plugins ] ***************************
Thursday 16 March 2023  11:57:56 +0000 (0:00:00.043)       0:01:27.698 ******** 
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-plugin", "install", "https://repo.xxxx.zip", "--allow-root"], "delta": "0:00:04.902068", "end": "2023-03-16 11:58:01.359526", "msg": "", "rc": 0, "start": "2023-03-16 11:57:56.457458", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Attempting to transfer from https://repos.xxxx.zip\nTransferring 30732982 bytes....................\nTransfer complete\nRetrieving metadata from plugin archive\nExtracting plugin archive\nExtraction complete\nPlugin installation complete", "stdout_lines": ["Attempting to transfer from https://repos.xxxx.zip", "Transferring 30732982 bytes....................", "Transfer complete", "Retrieving metadata from plugin archive", "Extracting plugin archive", "Extraction complete", "Plugin installation complete"]}
```

**The playbook will end with **Job Failed****

```
Idempotence test ${test_name}: fail
Failure for test ${test_name}
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 42
```

In **.gitlab-ci.yml** I have the following **tests(3 scenarious)**:

```
# check_mode + normal run + idempotence
    - >
      for something in $test ;
      do
      echo "Testing check_mode with tag $something"
      && ansible-playbook tests/test.yml --check -v --diff --tags 
    "test,$something" -e tag="$something"
      && echo "Currently testing with tag $something"
      && (ansible-playbook tests/test.yml -v --diff --tags 
    "test,$something" -e tag="$something"
      || (pgrep --list-full node ; ss -ant ;echo "Run $something: fail"; 
    exit 2))
      && echo "Testing idempotence with tag $something"
      && ((set +o pipefail ; ansible-playbook tests/test.yml -v -- 
    diff --tags "test,$something" -e tag="$something" -e 
      idempotence=True
      | tee idempotence.log
      | grep -qE 'changed=0.*failed=0')
      && (echo "Idempotence test $something: pass" && exit 0)
      || (cat idempotence.log && echo "Idempotence test $something: 
 fail" 
   && exit 1))
      || (echo "Failure for test $something" && exit 3)
      || exit 42 ;
      done
```

Comment: have you tried using `kibana_plugin` module? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/kibana_plugin_module.html

Comment: unfortunately we are using an old elk version as 7.10.2 for the moment and the kibana_plugin is checking the kibana version and every time I get " error" because I have an old version.